# How to trap the result of PageStateMatcher and send it to content.js

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I decomposed my use case for extension and individual part works.

1. Extension1: PageStateMatcher and ShowPageAction works in background.js well for a set of condition
2. Extension2: Content.js is able to manipulate the DOM of URLs based on a set of conditions in content.js
3. When I merge both, set of conditions being same, I am not able to trap the value of PageStateMatcher.

**How** should I capture the condition evaluation in background.js and send to content.js. I can potentially evaluate twice, in both the js, but it is not a good idea because of large number of conditions (about 100K urls)

manifest.js

```
     {
    "name": "Website condition validation extension.",
    "version": "1.1",
    "description": "This extension works if a website condition is set to true",
   "permissions": ["declarativeContent", "tabs"],
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },
    "page_action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_icon": {
        "16": "favicon-16x16.png",
        "32":  "favicon-32x32.png",
        "48": "android-chrome-192x192.png",
        "128": "android-chrome-192x192.png"
      }
    },
    "icons": {
       "16": "favicon-16x16.png",
        "32":  "favicon-32x32.png",
        "48": "android-chrome-192x192.png",
        "128": "android-chrome-192x192.png"
    },
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "manifest_version": 2,
      "content_scripts": [
    {
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": ["content_script.js"],
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "run_at": "document_idle"
    }
  ]
  }
```

background.js

```
/** Step 1: Declare a flag
 *  Step 2: Set the flag to true if a rule fires based on host name
 *  Step 3: Pass the flag to content.js in a message
 *  Step 4: Content.js receives the flag value
 *  Step 5: Content.js manipulates the URL's DOM based on condition. 
 * **/

//This flag is set to true is a condition rule is fired
let isARuleFired=false;
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function () {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function () {
        chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
            conditions:
            [               
               'becu.org',
                '.hopecu.org',
                '.square.site',
            ].map(s => {new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({ pageUrl: { hostSuffix: s } });isARuleFired=true;})
            , actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction(), isARuleFired=true] 

        }
        ]);
    });
});

//Logging to check the value
console.log("MYFLAG IS:"+myflag);

//The condition rule firing status is sent as message to content.js. This is NOT evaluated
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab){
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {ruleStatus:isARuleFired}, function(response){
        alert(response) // response not needed but I can swallow it
        $("#text").text(response);
    });
});
```

Comment: getCurrent() runs each time when the background script is started/resumed, not when the condition matches. There's no way to bind ShowPageAction to any custom code. Also, getCurrent doesn't do what you think, it's useless here. If I understand the goal correctly you need to remove getCurrent() block and use [RequestContentScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent#type-RequestContentScript) action instead of `ShowPageAction` (and instead of `content_scripts` section). It's actually supported in stable Chrome despite what the documentation says.

Comment: @wOxxOm does conditionally including content.js on rule match and messaging work? Message will be listened to only if the rule is fired? Code snippet below.
...<conditions  block>
"actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.RequestContentScript({
 js: [ 'content.js']
}),new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]"
//manifest.json same as above w/o "content_scripts"
Only either of action works. I want ShowPageAction also apart from DOM manipulation. Sorry Am a JS nube

Comment: I didn't know that only one action works (sounds like a bug, but I'm not surprised). Personally, I would switch to `browser_action` and just toggle the icon explicitly via chrome.browserAction.setIcon because `page_action` was castrated a few years ago and no longer does what it was designed to do.

Comment: @wOxxOm Probably my coding error. I will follow your suggestion. I am learning :)